# returning a View from a method inside a Class annotated with @RestController

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I generated the project from Spring Initialzr online.
Below is my Controller and the method i am using. Here `breedService.getAllDogsByBreedName(breed)` will provide me with all the dogs coming under that particular entered "breed". However the returned object "breed1" is JSON and is displayed in the browser with all the details of the dogs.

I want to represent it in an html or jsp view to make it presentable. Is there any way that i can pass the JSON results for "Labrador" obtained in the attached pic below to an html or jsp? or if there is any method to acheive this Please be considerate to help me, Thank you.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Disney")
public class BreedInfoController {


@RequestMapping(value = "/{breed}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json" })
    @ResponseBody
    public BreedMaster getBreedNameofDogs(@PathVariable("breed") String breed) {

        Breed breed1 = breedService.getAllDogsByBreedName(breed);
        return breed1;
    }

}
```

[image: Image of Json response of "breed1", which I have to make use in a jsp or html]

Comment: It does exactly what you instructed it to do, return the result as is. If you don't want that, don't use a `@RestController` but `@Controller` and use something like Thymeleaf to create a HTML. Or use basic HTML and JS and use AJAX to call the controller and dynamically create the view.

Comment: Thank you for responding, Yeah with @Controller it is possible to return a view, but this is the intermediate Stage which i have to keep, the JSON response. that's why i was curious whether there is a way to pass the JSON object.
Meanwhile if i use @ Controller then i have to use web.xml which i dont want, because i have to package this as a .jar file, looking forward for your guidance and help, Thank you :)

Comment: No you don't... `@Controller` and `@RestController` are basically the same (`@RestController` is nothing more the `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` combined).  Your statement that you have to use a `web.xml` when using `@Controller` is just wrong.

Comment: okay, so views can be returned only with @Controller and doesn't require web.xml configuration, so how can i configure <bean>...</bean> and <component scan>....</> then?

Comment: Why would you need to... As stated there is no difference between `@Controller` and `@RestController`... (Check the sources). A `@RestController` is just a `@Controller` (with an implicit `@ResponseBody` for all `@RequestMapping` methods).

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for your insights, appreciate it :)